# Overloaded methods in the class must have different Erasures - why only leftmost bound is considered to be the Erasure type?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure, jls, erasure

Consider the following two method definitions:

```java
static <T extends Do & Done>T whatToDo(T ele){return null;}
static <R extends Done & Do>R whatToDo(R ele){return null;}
```

Both will have the following erasures respectively:

```java
static Do whatToDo(Do);
static Done whatToDo(Done);
```

Consider the concrete class `Doing` and the interfaces `Do` and `Done`

```java
interface Do{void doIt();}

interface Done{void didIt();}

class Doing implements Do,Done{
    @Override
    public void doIt() {}
    
    @Override
    public void didIt() {

    }
}
```

Now, when I try to invoke the method `whatToDo`, this gives the ambiguous invocation compilation error, even though the methods got compiled in the class correctly. Only at the time of invocation, I am getting error.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    whatToDo(new Doing()); //compile error : ambiguous method call
}
```

Does it not mean that the definition of erasure is responsible for anomaly, that only the left most element is treated as the erasure for a given bounded type? Also, why has erasure been chosen to be this way? Can there be something better for the way JLS defines the procedure of erasure?

Ideal would have been that Java shouldn't have allowed the two methods in this case to exist by modifying the definition of erasure to include the unordered set of bounds rather than just the leftmost bound?

Here is the complete code:

```java
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    whatToDo(new Doing()); 
    //Compilation error : because of Erasure - the 2 definitions exist even though the
    //the elements of the bounds are exactly the same
    //Ideally this should have been unordered list of bounds rather than left most bound?
    }
    static <T extends Do & Done>T whatToDo(T ele){return null;}
    static <R extends Done & Do>R whatToDo(R ele){return null;}
}
interface Do{void doIt();}
interface Done{void didIt();}
class Doing implements Do,Done{
    @Override
    public void doIt() {}

    @Override
    public void didIt() {

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you propose the erasure of a type parameter `T` with bounds `U1 & U2 & .. Un` be then? Remember, it has to be available at runtime! Intersection types are not available at runtime!

Comment: Actually, I can't compile with both `<T extends Do & Done>T` and `<R extends Done & Do>R` methods. Java11 gives an error "Scratch.java:5: error: method <T>whatToDo(T) is already defined in class Scratch
    static <R extends Done & Do>R whatToDo(R ele){return null;}"

Comment: @geobreze Oh, so it's another case of IntelliJ IDEA not red-underlining it. IntelliJ misses so many compiler errors these days...

Comment: @Sweeper : the compiler must prevent the compilation of the 2 definitions of `whatToDo` in this case - coz they are different **merely on the basis of ordering of the intersection types in the bounds.** - and compiler is doing this only because of the way **erasure computation has been defined.**

Comment: But this we can see - is causing a miss at later stages of invocation.

Comment: Are you responding to my deleted comment? I realised I was wrong. Your code produces an error without the invocation of `whatToDo` as well. Try actually compiling your code! This is specified in the spec too, though you need to jump around a bit. Start at [§8.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) then work your way through what it means for two methods to have "the same type parameters".